# mock resttemplate to test a service as restFul client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service class, written in spring, with some methods.

One of this acts as a restful consumer like below:

```
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(getHeadersForRequest());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = ENDPOINT_URL.concat(ENDPOINT_API1);

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                                        .queryParam("param1", parameter1);
ReportModel infoModel = null;
try {
    infoModel = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),
                    HttpMethod.GET, request, ReportModel.class).getBody();
} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to use `Mockito` to mock my service, but every method that interacts with restful server instance a `new RestTemplate`.

I've to create a static class to Inject it into my service?

Comment: Which mocking framework do you use? Also, it would be **a lot** easier if you could use dependency injection to inject the `RestTemplate` rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the benefits from dependency injection is to be able to easily mock your dependencies. In your case it would be a lot easier to create a `RestTemplate` bean:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And in stead of using `new RestTemplate()` in your client you should use:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

For the unit testing with Mockito you'll have to mock the `RestTemplate`, for example by using:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private Client client;
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
}
```

In this case Mockito will mock and inject the `RestTemplate` bean in your `Client`. If you don't like mocking and injecting through reflection you can always go for a separate constructor or setter to inject the `RestTemplate` mock.

Now you can write a test like this:

```
client.doStuff();
verify(restTemplate).exchange(anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpModel.class), eq(ReportModel.class));
```

You'll probably want to test more than that, but it gives you a basic idea.

Comment: Yes, this's the way! Thank you so much

Comment: @g00glen00b Hi it does not work, I am getting HTTP URL must not be null error

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to mock `restTemplate` using Mockito, because instance is created with a `new` keyword.

Instead you should try to create a mock object in the test class:

```
mock(RestTemplate.class)
```

and pass it to the service class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've to use a static calss that instantiate a restTemplate and inject it?

Comment: I'd rather add the field to store `restTemplate` and create package-visible constructor to inject the mock.